# PhP Session Destruction not as eXpected

Tags: ubuntu, php, cron, session

I have added this code to  the top of  my page and it is executed when a user login.

```
<?php
$lifetime=86400;session_start();setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime,"/","","TRUE","TRUE");
?>
```

My intention is to increase the session life time to +1 day since the last access.
But for some reason this is not working, session expires after an indefinite x amount of time even though my browser indicates that the session will expire +1 day when i check the  console. 
I am running my web application on apache and an ubuntu environment.
By doing a few search in my info.php file i found this as my local value

```
session.cookie_lifetime 0
session.gc_divisor  1000    
session.gc_maxlifetime  86400
session.gc_probability  1
```

To my best of knowledge i think ubuntu is doing gabbage collection in the /var/lib/php/sessions folder with cron jobs because i am using windows as a   development environment and i don't see any of that happen.

my question is. Have i done anything wrong or am i right to say ubuntu is doing gabbage collection,so it will be advisable to change the session.save_path and if so what is the best way to that esp allowing permissions

Comment: Change `session.gc_maxlifetime` to double the current value and it should work for you.

Comment: Can i you explain further  why  should it be so  b'cos  it was half of that i.e 43200 and i doubled it to 86400 and i still have the same issues ...............so why would 2*86400 work for me

Comment: Is there maybe some other script that overrides these prarmeters? If so, then using your own `session.save_path` could make sense. Put it under some directory under your own control, but outside the document root. It needs to be writeable by the webserver user, probably www-data. Note that you are expicitly setting a cookie lifetime, which is only used to identify the session, the session data is separate from the cookie. And setting `session.cookie_lifetime` is probably easier than your way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i tried my suggestions and it worked well for me

Comment: i created a new folder to hold my session bcos ubuntu does routine  clean up  of session variables  which is  30 minutes old ...................